# Web Farm Framework fails to mirror to Secondary server

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-farm-framework

I've been dealing with trying to get the Web Farm Framework working correctly for awhile now and it's just not working. If I can't find a solution I'm going to have to look at another product or do dual deploys out of our build server.

The setup is that I have a controller setup. I've added servers in every way possible, either setting up the servers or trying to get WFF to do it and nothing is working. Here's what is working:

- Controller - WFF installed and working
- Primary Server - Only IIS management services installed.
- Secondary Server - Only IIS management services installed.

The two servers are on a NetScaler load balancer, but I have other servers that are on the Microsoft NLB and the behavior is the same.

The setup went like this:

1. Added a new Server Farm to WFF
2. Added Primary Server (Running operation AddServer)
3. Everything looks good (Web Farm Agent pushed out to Primary Server, Server Started Successfully in logs)
4. Provisioned WDeploy_v2 (Web Deploy 2.1) through the WFF to push out to the Primary Server. Got a warning about downloading the Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller but that was expected, it wasn't on the Primary Server
5. The various other products were added (SQL Server stuff, etc.) all installed correctly and server was successfully started. Logged onto the physical Primary server and everything was installed and looked good.
6. Added Secondary Server
7. All the various products installed including Web Deploy 2.1 and were added to the server. Logged onto the Secondary Server and they were there, a copy from the Primary server
8. The WFF compared the secondary server to the primary (Diffing local application WinServer () with primary server SERVERNAME)
9. The next line was an error.

Failed to run operation 'RunRemote'.  Failed to run method 'Microsoft.Web.Farm.SyncApplicationsRemoteMethod' on server 'SECONDARYSERVERNAME' Exception in response stream.  Object of type 'webServer' and path '' cannot be created.  (2/15/2013 10:18:15 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.  Object of type 'webServer' and path '' cannot be created.  One or more entries in the manifest 'webServer' are not valid.  Cannot find configuration file '/'.  Could not find file 'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\config\web.config'.  Exception in response stream.  Object of type 'webServer' and path '' cannot be created.  (2/15/2013 10:18:15 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.  Object of type 'webServer' and path '' cannot be created.  One or more entries in the manifest 'webServer' are not valid.  Cannot find configuration file '/'.  Could not find file 'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\config\web.config'.

I checked on the Secondary server in the path and the file is there. The WFF account that's configured for the farm is a local admin (on all servers) and has access to it.

At this point it runs a series of operations (RunRemote, ProvisionApplications, AddServer) all failing. It marks the server as Unhealthy, runs the operation DisableLoadBalancing and then attempts autorepair 10 times.

Each autorepair it fails on the same error RunRemote after Diffing the server with the primary (it actually successfully executes RunRemote, QueryInstalledProducts, and ServiceControl successfully before failing on the compare).

Basically replication is failing from Primary to Secondary when it gets ot the point of checking for differences.

Like I said I literally have tried everything so this is my last attempt at fixing it or getting rid of it altogether. The servers are load balanced with NetScaler so I've tried both configured as ready for loadbalancing enabled and disabled (as far as WFF goes). No difference. The servers are running with UAT turned on (which always seems to have issues). We can do a Web Deploy (once the app is installed) via TeamCity or command line to deploy websites remotely to the server so I know all of that is working. Just can't get WFF going properly.

And it works fine with one server, it's just when you add the secondary server it fails. Another test I just finished was doing it with one server as primary and the other as secondary, then completely uninstalling everything, rebooting both, and changing it with the secondary server set as pirmary and primary as secondary (just to see if maybe the original secondary server just had problems taking orders). Both primary servers always work.

Hopefully someone can help. Very frustrating as there's little documentation out there and any kind of error messages people have posted are "similar" to this situation but not exact. Any similar setups I've tried the various fixes and none of them work. In addition I set things up cleanly as above so it *should just work* but doesn't.

Also the environment: All servers are Server 2008 x64 R2. Servers have internet access and the firewall services are not running.

One more update. After having it setup and getting the failure on the secondary server whenever it trys to sync primary to secondary I set the secondary as primary (right click context menu). It flipped over and exactly the same behavior. Now the new Primary server is fine but the new Secondary fails as it tries to execute the RunRemote operation.

Thanks!